# Where does meteor install on Mac?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I installed meteor and created an app following tut
http://docs.meteor.com/#quickstart

In finder, I searched meteor but I can't find it.

Comment: Not really programming related is it?

Comment: Are you kidding ? Meteor is a node.js sdk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/usr/local/meteor` - you can find that in the install script from http://install.meteor.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'm absolute beginner. I read doc but it just presents principles a lot of details are missing. I can't find where it did create myapp also for example.

Comment: That'll be in the current working directory where you created the app.

Answer (score 8):

As a more general solution, the bash shell command `type` accomplishes this for any command:

```
    $ type meteor
    meteor is /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

For other shells, see [this excellent answer over at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/351995/257781).